# Flutter: Checking (e) for error type after catch

Tags: flutter

I have the following code to log a user in using Firebase Auth. I'd like to display an error if the password is wrong, but not sure how to test e to see what error happened.

```
    try {
      final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
      }
      setState(() {
        showSpinner = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {          
      if (e.errorCode = ???) {      <--- how to test e for the type of error ???
        print(e.error);
      }
    }
```

Thanks for any help,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase docs can help you with finding all the error codes. When e.code matches with a particular firebase auth code, you can generate your relevant error message.

For instance, for a wrong password entered you could do this.

```
if (e.code.contains('ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD')) {
    errorText = 'Wrong Password';
    print(errorText);
```

Some of the error codes are - `ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD`, `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL`, `ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE`, `ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help!!